# CMS Made Simple some images and all pages not found after moving servers

Tags: http-status-code-404, cmsmadesimple

After moving my site from one server to another I now have the problem that some of the images are not showing and only the home page will show all other pages when linked to give a 404 error:

Not Found

The requested URL /location.html was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: In my case I was I was transferring to a dedicated server. It is worth noting that if you are testing before you change the DNS you may need to update the mod_rewrite settings within the .htacess file to include RewriteBase "/~accountName/". Initially only my home page was showing, after adding the proper RewriteBase everything worked perfectly. Of course you will need to change this back once you update DNS to point to the new server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be any number of things given that information.  Things to check:

- Database connection settings in config.php
- Any special settings in .htaccess
- Path setting in config.php
- Has your URL changed? If so adjust line in config.php

If no joy, post your system info (Admin area -> Site Admin -> System Information -> View Text Report link (top right)).  And preferably a link to the site.  And describe the steps you took to move the site from server to server.

Comment: Thanks, it was the .htaccess file I downloaded a new one from here: http://dev.cmsmadesimple.org/project/files/711 and replaced the old one and fixed everything.

Comment: In my case I forgot to import the database and this yielded a 404 error.